# How Can I Read Where TempDB's Files Will Be Created After Restoring Master DB?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, startup, system-databases

I'm restoring to an alternate server in a DR drill and have restored master but can't restart the instance, even with /f and /m switches. The log is indicating tempdb can't be created, probably looking for the paths from the source instance. How can I determine which path it's trying to create tempdb's DB files in?

I was able to restore the master backup under an alternate name on a different instance so I can browse the system tables. Is there a spot where I can look for them?

I have to go with the assumption that access to the source server is lost so I can only rely on the backups to determine the correct configuration.

Comment: Added a link for Recovery

Comment: Check the SQL Server log for error messages.  It'll tell you the location for `tempdb`.  Typically, this would be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG`

Comment: Review your documentation you have on production that should have this information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Instance will not start](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/the-sql-server-instance-that-will-not-start/)

There is a section called: `TempDB location does not exist`, you should be able to see the location in the SQL server log

Comment: Re-read the OP's question and you will realize your solution is not going to work...

Comment: @ShawnM .. It was clarified after my initial post. Therefore I have modified answer to include link `Instance will not start` and the OP can go from there.

Comment: Then you should remove the first portion of your answer that does not apply. You can also easily summarize Gail's fix for tempdb issue in a few statements and reference the article for more details.

Comment: @ShawnMelton .. Done

Comment: Thanks @t_m. Trace flag 3608 did the trick to allow me to read the sys.master_files table.

Answer (score 0):

Start SQL Server in minimal config mode, master only configuration, 
from a command prompt:

```
[path to this instance]\Binn\sqlservr.exe -c -f -T3608
```

(Add -s InstanceName incase it is named instance.)

Now, in a different command prompt, connect using SQLCMD:

```
> sqlcmd -E
```

now change the path of the tempdb and shutdown

```
> ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, filename = 'E:\Data\tempdb.mdf');
> ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, filename = 'E:\Data\tempdb.mdf');
> SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT;
> GO
```

Now start SQL Server

Comment: Re-read the OP's question and you will realize your solution is not going to work...

Comment: @ShawnMelton , yes read it again, it was modified so I have modified my answer.Thanks :)